# Failed to execute 'getImageData' (cross-origin)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, cross-domain

I'm trying to get the pixels from a canvas, but when I do that I get the following error in chrome:

```
VM244:724 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

[image]

Why does this give a security error ? But most importantly is there a way to tell chrome to ignore this security error (I'm only doing this on my machine!)

Comment: Have you tried using this switch `--allow-file-access-from-files` for chrome?  Be good if you could show actual code - it's maybe going to make a difference to the answer.  If you're retrieving from a local web app that you can control, add the following header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. If you go, as an example, to http://agar.io and start playing, you can produce the same error as shown in the screen shot. Furthermore I assume that the `allow-file-access-from-files` can be set in `chrome://flags`, right ? I'm using chrome 50, and I can't find anything close to that setting (I don't start chrome from the command line)

Comment: Be nice if they added it, but right now it's a command line option - but you can set command line in the system's command line

Comment: ok, so I tried `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` but I still get the error. Is this the right way to run chrome with args from the command line ?

Comment: ignore the chrome options and go with the linked duplicate.  Since this is canvas tainting I'm not sure chrome is going to treat it as a file:// url anyway.

Comment: That post doesn't answer my question. I don't want to fix the problem, I simply want to disable it locally only

Comment: You can"t disable it, all you can do is fix the original document so it includes the correct CORS headers

Comment: But I can't manipulate the headers from http://agar.io for example, so what would be a possible solution?

Comment: Getting image data locally is not the same as getting it from agar.io. it does not matter if the page is being run locally, the image data is **not** local so the cross domain policy applies.  If agar.io does not have the correct headers you won't be able to use their data

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear, but with local I mean that it is fine if it only works on my machine (for development). Other people are indeed asking similar questions, but they are building some kind of site which incorporate something external canvas

Comment: Does it help if I would use a proxy which sets `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on all responses